# Exception in JPA Persistance

Tags: java, jpa

I have question...I Have two JAR file, which have similar code, and one is in English and second for Deutch...I have two DB (for EN a DE), but I want to have same table names. If I start this, I have two definitions for same table...I want to keep the table same for the JAR, which will change. But it's enough for me to load one of this two. How can I do it? My app is bigger...

I don't want the modification of one table definition to be written to both tables.

Some advice? In persistance you can see some solve? Thanks

```
<jar-file>FA_DE-MLA-1.0.jar</jar-file>
<jar-file>FA_EN-MLA-1.0.jar</jar-file>

<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none" />
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.create_empty_composites.enabled" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: What exception?

Comment: processing exception in persistance.xml

Comment: Again, what exception? Would you post the exception details (copy-paste)?

Comment: I want to create an exception to handle only one JAR, podle parametru for example in project-defaults

Comment: This work right, but I want change it..